# Line split when multiple white spaces in python

Tags: python, sed, split, tabs, space

I looked though many similar questions, however my separators are not special characters such as "\" or "*", therefore none of the solutions worked.
I am writing my results to a file in python, and re-opening it to read and process.

```
file1.txt
control1
1  10      12
1  34      44
2   1      -3
control2
3   4     -10.3
3   3.390   4
```

I separate each entry until I see a line having 'control' into `chapters`:

```
import re
import sys, string, glob, os
with open('file1.txt') as f:
        with open("control_output.txt", "w") as output:
            mytext = f.read()
            chapter = re.split("control[0-2]+\n", mytext)
            i=1
            print chapter[i]
            output.write(chapter[i])
            for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(filePath, 'control_output.txt')):
                 merged_table=open(filename,'r')
                 for line in merged_table:
                      line = line.strip().split('\t')
                      print line
```

However it prints nothing, as the line does not have a tab separator.
If I go out of the script before reading the file, and change all whitespaces to tabs, then it works:

```
sed -i 's/ \+ /\t/g' control_output.txt
```

Then I have the output:

```
['1', '10', '12']
['1', '34', '44']
['2', '1', '-3']
```

I also tried with subprocess.call however

```
subprocess.call(["sed", "-i",  's/ \+ /\t/g', "control_output.txt"])
```

Then I have the output of:

```
[[]]
```

I tried re.split with multiple white spaces:

```
line = re.split(r'\s*', line)
```

Which also gave

```
[[]]
```

However the expected output should be :

```
['1', '10', '12']
['1', '34', '44']
['2', '1', '-3']
```

How do I split string with multiple delimiters?

Comment: Splitting with multiple whitespaces with regex in Python is done with `line = re.split(r'\s+', line)`. `\s*` will match before any non-matching symbol.

Comment: Did you try simply `line.strip().split()`?

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: I added the expected output.  I tried both of your solutions.. I have an empty list as an output with these

Answer (score 3):

```
for line in merged_table:
    line = line.strip().split()
        print line
```

This will split on all whitespace and not just tabs

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I still have empty output with this solution : [[]]

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
import sys, string, glob, os
with open('file1.txt') as f:
    with open("control_output.txt", "w") as output:
        mytext = f.read()
        chapter = re.split("control[0-2]+\n", mytext)
        i=1
        print chapter[i]
        output.write(chapter[i])

    # You should move this code block out of with open("control_output.txt", "w") as output:
    for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(filePath, 'control_output.txt')):
        with open(filename, 'r') as f_table:
            merged_table = f_table.readlines()

        for line in merged_table:
            line = re.split('\s+', line.strip())
            print line
```

Hope to help you